# Jquery modal not working: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dialog'

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have an MVC4 page which allows a user to select and image and add comments to it before saving to a database. The page also has a jquery modal dialog which is used to upload a new image to a directory.

This was all working fine but after migrating the VS2013 project to a new machine it seems to have stopped working, in the browser using IIS Express or the published version I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dialog'

I've tried following other posts which suggest that Jquery is defined too many times or in the wrong order but this does not seem to solve my issue.

The _Layout page is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - ourLeaderboard</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")


    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css")"
          rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css")"
          rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css")"
          rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.core.min.js")"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.js")"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/DatePickerReady.js")"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#my-dialog').dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 400,
                resizable: false,
                modal: true
            });

            $('.modal').click(function () {
                $('#my-dialog').load(this.href, function () {
                    $(this).dialog('open');
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Pyecombe Golf Club", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Competitions", "Index", "Competition")</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - ourLeaderboard, (C) Pyecombe Golf Club</p>
            <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")"
                    type="text/javascript"></script>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css", "~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

and my view is as follows:

```
    @model ourLeaderboardDev.Models.Message
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Upload Image";
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 400,
            resizable: false,
            title: 'TheTitle',
            modal: true,
            open: function(event, ui) {

            },
            buttons: {
                "Close": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

        $('.ShowDialogButton').click(function () {
            $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        });
    });
</script>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Competition News</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Message1, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Message1)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Message1)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Message2, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Message2, new SelectList(ViewBag.myFiles).AsEnumerable())
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Message3, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Message3)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Message3)
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}



<a href="#" class="ShowDialogButton">Upload Image</a>
<div id="dialog" class="dialog" title="TheTitle" style="overflow: hidden;">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "Admin", null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "FileUploadForm", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <input type="file" name="files" id="file1" size="50" />
        <input type="submit" id="submitFiles" name="submit" value="Upload Document" />
    }
    </div>
```

Comment: The html you have has only one element with id `dialog` and there is no element with id my-dialog

Answer (score 0):

Check that you include

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.dialog.min.js")"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
```

in your code

Comment: this could go in comments! Besides loading a specific `library file` for each type of methods like `datepicker` and `dialogs`, only one common `jquery-ui.js` file can be used which comprise of all widgets and methods. Same can be done for `css` files (both are included in package). Then you do not have to worry about using any method/effect in future.

Comment: I haven't reputation for this.